# Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug

Tags: android-studio, firebaseui

The moment I add  implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.1' into the dependencies, this exception is caused. 
The project build is completed successfully. But at runtime, it fails.
I have checked the compatibilities of Firebase dependencies, Tried adding multiDexEnabled, tried cleaning and rebuilding.. nothing worked. Please help.

Here are the files:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.leena.mypills"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
//        multiDexEnabled true

}
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
 }

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
//  implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'



//    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

--

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all   sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

--- full trace:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\175.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\176.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\177.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\178.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\179.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\180.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\181.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\182.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\183.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\184.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\185.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\186.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\187.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\188.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\189.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\190.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\191.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\192.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\193.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\194.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\195.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\196.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\197.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\198.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\199.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\200.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\201.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\202.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\203.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\204.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\205.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\206.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\207.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\208.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\209.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\210.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\211.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\212.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\213.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\214.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\215.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\216.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\217.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\218.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\219.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\221.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\222.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\223.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\225.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\226.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\227.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\228.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\229.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\230.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\231.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\232.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\233.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\234.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\235.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\236.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\237.jar
at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor685.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
... 32 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\175.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\176.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\177.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\178.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\179.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\180.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\181.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\182.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\183.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\184.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\185.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\186.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\187.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\188.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\189.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\190.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\191.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\192.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\193.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\194.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\195.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\196.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\197.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\198.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\199.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\200.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\201.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\202.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\203.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\204.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\205.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\206.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\207.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\208.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\209.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\210.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\211.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\212.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\213.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\214.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\215.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\216.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\217.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\218.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\219.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\221.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\222.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\223.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\225.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\226.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\227.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\228.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\229.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\230.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\231.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\232.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\233.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\234.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\235.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\236.jar, C:\Users\leena\Desktop\MyPills\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\237.jar
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:124)
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:109)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:101)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ExternalLibsMergerTransform.transform(ExternalLibsMergerTransform.kt:123)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
... 47 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:76)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:45)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:67)
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:107)
... 52 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:77)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:58)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:67)
... 55 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the firebase version(11.0.2) and used an earlier version and it started working. And firebase UI version is 2.1.1

Comment: Could you give some more details, please? E.g. the firebase version, you're using to get it working. Thanks.

Comment: firebase version 11.0.2